# Link to app store for update - works iPhone not on iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am using the link: itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=APP_ID&mt=8

(with APP_ID replaced by the ID of the app)

It works just fine iPhone (iOS4.3 & iOS5) but on iPad (iOS5) the link switches to AppStore but the page does not load "Cannot connect to the iTunes Store"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use the iTunes Link maker:

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/

Just insert your app name, select iOS App, and it will generate the link for you.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, not as good as the link above which opens App Store app right at the update page for the app.
Finally found changing "viewSoftwareUpdate" to "viewSoftware" works - not as clean, but opens the iPad app page, which has an 'Update' link.