# Link to Developer Page Doesn't Work on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, url, hyperlink, app-store

I want a link to show my apps from within my apps, I'm currently using the following url format:

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/developername
```

Which I got from this thread:

[How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)

It works fine on the iPhone but on the iPad it doesn't load anything in the App Store app, it's a blank page.

I have found another questions asking the same thing but have yet to find an answer

[Link to app store for update - works iPhone not on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159792/link-to-app-store-for-update-works-iphone-not-on-ipad)

Anyone got this issue too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple just annonced the appstore.com urls, just tested it out on iOS 7 and it's working on the ipad with affiliate links.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

> There are three types of App Store Short Links, in two forms, one for iOS apps, another for Mac Apps:
>
> ### Company Name
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/apple
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple
>
> ### App Name
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/keynote
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac/ for example, http://appstore.com/mac/keynote
>
> ### App by Company
>
> iOS: http://appstore.com// for example, http://appstore.com/apple/keynote
>
> Mac: http://appstore.com/mac// for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple/keynote
>
> Most companies and apps have a canonical App Store Short Link. This canonical URL is created by changing or removing certain characters (many of which are illegal or have special meaning in a URL (for example, "&")).
>
> ### To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your company or app name:
>
> Remove all whitespace
>
> Convert all characters to lower-case
>
> Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
>
> Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
>
> Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
>
> Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
>
> Leave all other characters as-is.
>
> Listing 2  Punctuation characters that must be removed.
>
> !¡"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>¿?@[]^_`{|}~
>
> Below are some examples to demonstrate the conversion that takes place.
>
> ### App Store
>
> ### Company Name examples
>
> Gameloft => http://appstore.com/gameloft
>
> Activision Publishing, Inc. => http://appstore.com/activisionpublishinginc
>
> Chen's Photography & Software => http://appstore.com/chensphotographyandsoftware
>
> ### App Name examples
>
> Ocarina => http://appstore.com/ocarina
>
> Where’s My Perry? => http://appstore.com/wheresmyperry
>
> Brain Challenge™ => http://appstore.com/brainchallenge

Answer (score 1):

Okay I managed to get it working by removing the apps part from the URL. i.e.

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/developername
```

I hope this may help someone else.